# Loading Additional STIGs in SCAP Compliance Checker

Tags: security

I have been evaluating the SCAP Compliance Checker tool (https://www.niwcatlantic.navy.mil/scap/).  It comes with a reasonable set of pre-loaded STIGs, but I'd like to add additional ones.  Although there is an "install" option for adding STIGs, I have so far been unsuccessful in finding any in a format that SCC will accept.  I've tried using STIGs from the National Checklist Program (https://ncp.nist.gov/repository) and UCF STIG Viewer (https://stigviewer.com/). The "official" source for STIGs for use in the SCC tool is https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/scap/, but it's a pretty limited list.  Has anyone successfully installed other STIGs in SCC?

Answer (score 0):

This was my own fault.  I didn't notice that I was trying to load prose (reference only) STIGs, instead of benchmarks.  I tested with a benchmark STIG (Solaris x86), and it loaded without errors.